# Ionic Android Build Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 [solution]

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm new to coding and also Ionic, but here is a solution to an issue that I faced, with an explanation for my situation.

I tried to `ionic build android` but it gave out an error message that ended with `Command failed with exit code 1`

The fix would be to `ionic platform remove android` and then add it back again with `ionic platform add android`.

Where it went wrong, I think, is that I updated my android's xml manifest, to update the name for the app. So if you did the same, this will definitely solve it for you.

Maybe someone out there can explain further, and point out a workaround that doesn't require removing the platform.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088224/ionic-build-error-cmd-command-failed-with-exit-code-1
my reputation is too low to comment on other threads

Answer (score 0):

Try running the android tools and installing the items below:

Open the SDK manager.
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-23
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)

Comment: I've installed Android SDK but not the SDK manager. I'll try this out. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and fixed it by just removing platform and again adding the same one.

**Remove Platform**

```
$ cordova platform remove android
```

**Add Platform**

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

just go to `'/home/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists/**'**`

delete everything inside of this

then **build** again.